# Issue with getting the correct date from NSDate

Tags: ios, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have some issues with `NSDate`.

The code I have looks like:

```
NSDate *date    = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:logout];
```

When I put my breakpoint at this code and move my mouse over, it shows as

```
2013-01-28 18:25:27 SGT
```

but when `NSLog` date

I get this:

```
2013-01-28 10:25:27
```

Why is this so? How do show the correct one?

Comment: You are from singapore and its GMT +8.00 hrs!! Your location matters a lot

Comment: how do u alter it? need some guidance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is just because **NSDate is a "raw" date. That's why it is in GMT**

You can try this,

```
NSDate* sourceDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:logout];

NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

NSDate* destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate];
```

this will give you your current timezone

Answer (score 1):

NSDate defines an object that represents a date with certain properties (such as timezone). If you wish to display a date, you could choose to show only it's year, maybe only the hours and minutes (all this can be done using the `NSDateFormatter` class). What you're doing is printing the object out on the LLDB - this shows you probably the UTC version of the date so I'm not surprised that the debugger summary of that same instance shows a different time.

Decide what you need to do with this date, set it's timezone accordingly, format it and print it out in your console.

Comment: am i right to say that lldb version code will be used in the device also right?

Comment: moreover, how do u set the timezone for NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:logout];

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this it works!!
  NSDate *localDate =[NSDate date]; // get the date

    NSTimeInterval timeZoneOffset = [[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];  

    NSTimeInterval gmtTimeInterval = [localDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + timeZoneOffset;

    NSDate *gmtDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:gmtTimeInterval];

    NSLog(@"%@",gmtDate);
```